# Java Stream: How to avoid add null value in Collectors.toList()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, lightweight-stream-api

There is some Java code:

```
 List<Call> updatedList = updatingUniquedList 
      .stream()
      .map(s -> {
       Call call = callsBufferMap.get(s);
      }
        return call;
     }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to avoid avoid to add to final list if call variable is null ?

Comment: Alternate to `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` is `Collectors.filtering(Objects::nonNull, Collectors.toList()`. It depends on your taste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

before collecting. Or rewrite it to a simple foreach with an if.

Btw, you can do

```
.map(callsBufferMap::get)
```

Comment: Or with Java 9+: `List<Call> updatedList = updatingUniquedList .stream() .flatMap(s -> Stream.ofNullable(callsBufferMap.get(s))) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter(o -> o != null)` after `map` and before `collect`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options you can use:

1. using nonnull method in stream: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`
2. using removeIf of list: `updatedList.removeIf(Objects::isNull);`

So for example the lines can look like this:

```java
 List<Call> updatedList = updatingUniquedList
     .stream()
     .map(callsBufferMap::get)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
Collectors.filtering(Objects::nonNull, Collectors.toList())
```