# How do you remove "null" values from a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have a Java Stream that contains `null` values.

How do you remove them ?

Comment: You can't really remove them from a stream, but you can decide to ignore them… See your own answer for some ideas ;-)

Comment: @deHaar - `filter` is *really* removing the nulls from the `Stream`.  (It is not removing them from the *source* of the `Stream`, but you can't do that anyway.)

Comment: If you want evidence, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819470.   And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991118.  And I could probably find more.  The point is that this is a succinct question, where the others that I can find all require the reader to disentangle a bunch of context.

Comment: @StephenC OK, you are right, one can remove/ignore/filter values from the stream. The source stays untouched, that's what my first comment was supposed to say but used inappropriate terminology.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a few ways I can think of:

`stream.filter(x -> x != null).`

`stream.filter(Objects::nonNull)`